# Did Bond sleep with Eve?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, skyfall

In [*Skyfall*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1074638/), during the scene before Bond visits the casino in Macau, when Eve shaves him, it is not completely clear to me if they sleep with each other afterwards, although the atmosphere between them right before might imply it (and first made me sure that's what happened, until watching the movie again and not being that sure anymore). But maybe they didn't even have the time for it before getting ready for the casino anyway (but then again, when did Bond not have time for this?).

Now of course as we learn afterwards Eve is actually Eve Monneypenny and in the previous movies a general story fact was that there has never been anything physical between them, which actually was the reason for the tension and fun of their occasional flirts. But on the other hand *starting* the sexual tension between them with a physical act might also fit pretty well to the modern and much more active and self-confident version of Monneypenny introduced in the movie (and would actually emphasize this modernization even further).

So my pretty simple question is, **did Bond sleep with Eve that night?** Now this might of course have been intentionally left open for interpretation, but I might also just have missed something obvious and there is a more or less definite answer to this.

Comment: My initial reaction to this question was: 'why does this matter?' But the Moneypenny angle is a solid argument. +1

Comment: @stevvve Yeah, *Bond* doing *Moneypenny* right at the beginning gives a whole new aspect to the modernization of her and her relationship to *Bond*. In fact the introduction of 21st century versions of *Q* and *Moneypenny* is one of the (many) things I really like about *Skyfall*.

Comment: At the moment I'd say __NO__. Why? Because they _never kiss._ The sexual tension is a bit more palpable compared to the previous films, but I'd still consider it 'banter' as long as there is no (passionate) kissing. As far as I remember 'kissing the girl' has always preceded 'sleeping with the girl' in the previous movies.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For two reasons, I believe **Bond did not sleep with Eve Moneypenny**.

First, the Bond series usually makes it clear when James has sex with a woman. There are very few love scenes that are ambiguous -- but the scene with Eve is ambiguous.

Second, Skyfall introduces Moneypenny, but I don't think Skyfall changes the nature of her relationship with Bond -- and in all the preceding Bond movies that feature Bond and Moneypenny, their banter suggests he wants sex but she insists on commitment first. Moneypenny often mentions things like engagement rings, while Bond makes loads of sexual references. Also, their flirting consistently strikes me as having a hopeful tone suggestive of the tension of a relationship yet to be consummated -- not the more knowing tone suggestive of a prior, brief sexual relationship:

*Dr. No* (1962)

- Moneypenny: 007 is here sir.
  [Slaps Bond's hand away from the papers on her desk]
- Bond: Moneypenny! What gives?
- Moneypenny: Me, given an ounce of encouragement. You've never taken me to dinner looking like this. You've never taken me to dinner...
- Bond: I would, you know. Only "M" would have me court-martialed for... illegal use of government property.
- Moneypenny: Flattery will get you nowhere - but don't stop trying.

*Goldfinger* (1964)

- Bond: What do you know about gold, Moneypenny?
- Moneypenny: Oh, the only gold I know about is the kind you wear... you know, on the third finger of your left hand?
- Bond: Well, one of these days we really must look into that.
- Moneypenny: How about tonight? You'll come over for dinner...
  [playfully tosses Bond's hat onto the hat rack] and I'll cook you a wonderful angel cake.
- Bond: Well, nothing would give me greater pleasure, but I'm afraid I have a... business appointment.
- Moneypenny: [laughing] That's the flimsiest excuse you've ever given me. Oh, well, some girls have all the luck. Who is she, James?
- M: [over intercom] "She" is me, Miss Moneypenny. And kindly omit the customary byplay with 007. He's dining with me and I don't want him to be late.
- Moneypenny: [to Bond] Then there's hope for me yet.
- Bond: [gives Moneypenny a playful peck on the cheek] Moneypenny, won't you ever believe me?

*You Only Live Twice* (1967)

- M: [buzzing intercom] Miss Moneypenny, give 007 the password we've agreed with Japanese S.I.S.
- MoneyPenny: Yes sir. [to Bond] We tried to think of something that you wouldn't forget.
- Bond: Yes?
- MoneyPenny: "I, love, you". Repeat it please, to make sure you get it
- Bond: Don't worry, I get it.

*Diamonds Are Forever* (1971)

- Bond: What can I bring you back from Holland?
- Moneypenny: A diamond? In a ring?
- Bond: Would you settle for a tulip?
- Moneypenny: [Bond leaves; she sighs longingly] Mm, yes.

*GoldenEye* (1995)

- Bond: What would I ever do without you?
- Moneypenny: As far as I can remember, James, *you've never had me*.
- Bond: Hope springs eternal.
- Moneypenny: You know, this sort of behaviour could qualify as sexual harassment.
- Bond: Really? What's the penalty for that?
- Moneypenny: Someday, you'll have to make good on your innuendos.
- Bond: After you, Moneypenny.
- Moneypenny: No, I insist. You first.

*Tomorrow Never Dies* (1997)

- Bond: I doubt if she'll remember me.
- M: Remind her. Then pump her for information.
- Moneypenny: You'll just have to decide how much pumping is needed, James.
- Bond: If only that were true of you and I, Moneypenny.

*The World Is Not Enough* (1999)

- Moneypenny: James! Have you brought me a souvenir from your trip? Chocolates? An engagement ring?
- Bond: I thought you might enjoy one of these. [gives Ms. Moneypenny a cigar tube]
- Moneypenny: How romantic. I know exactly where to put that. [throws the cigar tube in the garbage]
- Bond: Oh Moneypenny, the story of our relationship: close, but no cigar.

Comment: I totally agree with your analysis of *Bond*'s relationship to *Monneypenny* in the pre-*Craig*-era and you might also be totally right with your extraploation of that onto *Skyfall*. But considering the heavy modernization her character underwent in *Skyfall*, I'm not completely sure if those arguments still hold that much (which is in fact the reason I asked this question). Of course it's still a *James Bond* movie, but since it's rather a reboot you cannot count too much on the previous movies for an explanation. But +1 anyway.

Comment: Ok, I see now that your reason for posting this answer was probably that from my question it may not have been completely clear that I'm totally aware of all the facts you posted. Rephrased it now (which unfortunately renders the answer a bit obsolete, but Ok, it's still a valid point and it's rather my fault of phrasing the question too ambigously).

Comment: I added more evidence of "not sleeping together" to my answer that might help. And I stand by my original reasoning: Skyfall introduces Moneypenny, but I don't think Skyfall changes the nature of her relationship with Bond.

Comment: Thanks, I stand by my original up-vote ;). Especially the new first reason isn't that unconvincing (being along the lines of *Oliver_C*'s comment). Feel free to add the last sentence of your comment into the answer, which IMHO better emphasizes the relevance of your second reason.

Answer (score 6):

According to canon (Director Sam Mendes's commentary on Blu-Ray release) Bond did NOT sleep with Eve in Macao.

Source: http://debrief.commanderbond.net/topic/63063-sam-mendes-commentary-amazing/

> Bond and Moneypenny do NOT become lovers in Macau. (This was an important point for him.)

Comment: Wow, this forum post makes me want to hear that commentary, love this movie. Thanks for the answer, certainly gonna check this further.

Answer (score 2):

The key clue for me was that, after the scene ends, the cut is to fireworks going off in the night sky.  That is a classic Bond style touch, cutting to an image that is full of sexual symbolism, like a train going through a tunnel, to hint at what they can't show on camera.  That's something that is an intentional choice by the writer/director, and they knew exactly what they were trying to convey to the audience.

Another subtler clue was the dialogue between Bond and Eve later, when they are joking about what you can do with two hands.  This is reminiscent of the dialogue in Casino Royale between Bond and Vespa about what he can do with his pinky, and Eve's response seems less like flirting and more like a genuine response.  So, I read that as a confirmation that something did happen between them, besides a close shave.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think that it's the same as many of the love scenes in all the Bonds.  You see Bond and the girl kissing then the camera fades out (or suddenly becomes very interested in a lampshade/curtain or other inanimate object).  The assumption is made that they sleep together but for the genre (not to mention the age rating) you never actually see it!

I think this is the same, it's heavily implied but you never actually see it.

Comment: *"You see Bond and the girl kissing then the camera fades out"* - But in fact as *Shane* and *Oliver_C* point out it isn't implied as unabiguously as in the many other love scenes. Though I also thought like you at first.